# Upgrading from Liferay 6.1.10 to Liferay 6.1.20

Tags: liferay-6

How to upgrade from Liferay 6.1.10 to Liferay 6.1.20 in a production environment? I haven't done this before, so might need some help/guide. As I understood from the searches, I need to download the 6.1.20 bundle, point to the database in the portal-ext.properties and start liferay. Is this the correct process? Thanks.

Comment: I managaed to do this, so everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory (assuming that there is no custom code - we bare Liferay) like this:

1. perform backup
2. stop portal
3. unzip next Liferay 6.1.1
4. Copy it (replacing) files settings (portal-ext.properties, portal-wizard-setup.properties and others - if you were), it is important to follow that would:
   сonnection settings copied to the database - that is, portal use the same database as the previous; **portal-setup-wizard.properties** correct **liferay.home** - that would be shown on a new directory (or, that which then will run a new version of Liferay)
5. copied from the old portal folder **"data"** and place it in the new.

That is, you get a new portal that looks into the old database and used old data. Further launching a new version Liferay.

At the start of Liferay itself has cut the base is old and will perform its update (automatically). After that, put all the additional portlets that were with you before.

This theory - practically there are deviations (for backup and done - that we could quickly rever back)

Comment: Thanks Segavax for the answer. Though your answer came late and managed to do this in May, but pretty much used the same steps as you have mentioned. So I mark this as an answer :)